# What option do I need in setup.py to create the package in the right directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, pip, setup.py

I am using `setup.py` to create a python package, which I want to install via `pip`. To correctly install the files under

```
lib/python2.7/site-packages/<package-name>
```

I used the following option in `setup.py`:

```
'package_dir': {'':'lib'}
```

as [described here](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) but get an error

```
error: package directory 'lib' does not exist
```

Well, there is no such directory as I want the *current* directory to be installed as package `lib` or whatever. I also tried to use

```
'package_dir': {'mycode':''}
```

which installes the code directly in

```
lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

and not under

```
lib/python2.7/site-packages/<package-name>
```

What am I doing wrong, and where is this documented? I might overlooked the documentation of this basic feature as the documentation for `setup.py` is 'suboptimal'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The description to how to do this an be found in the [distribute documentation](https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)... Within a directory containing all of the project (`TowelStuff/` in the given example) you specify the name of the actual module (`towelstuff/`). To include this as *your* module you need to add the following line in `setup.py`:

```
'packages': ['towelstuff']
```

After having created the sdist (from within `TowelStuff/`), the installation of this package will install it under `site-packages/towelstuff`, which can be imported as usual (`from towelstuff import ...`).